# Could not find io.fabric.tools::gradle1.24.1

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have an old app and it is giving theses error messages:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:classpath'.
   > Could not find io.fabric.tools::gradle1.24.1.
     Required by:
         project :app

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, 
   see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

`build.gradle` contents:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools::gradle1.24.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
```

I'm thinking this is because fabric url is no longer alive since its been migrated to firebase? I need to make it run without much modifcations. All fabric links are present on `build.gradle` file.

Comment: You will need to migrate to Firebase, Fabric was shutdown and the old SDKs no longer work. Check this document on how to upgrade: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?authuser=0&platform=android

Comment: Solution I did was just to comment every fabric code, it was only using crashlytics so not many changes.